# Is it possible to ignore one single filter attribute in MVC on a specific action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following filters registered

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new CompressContentAttribute());
            filters.Add(new MinifyHtmlAttribute());

            filters.Add(new MinifyXmlAttribute());
        }
```

I want to ignore `CompressContentAttribute()` on a specific action 
is it possible to do so in MVC .
I did various research , each of them show how to ignore entire filter attributes

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Filter Provider. This IFilterProvider interface has a method GetFilters.

```
public class SelectiveFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly List<Func<ControllerContext, object>> filterconditions = new List<Func<ControllerContext, object>>();
    public void Add(Func<ControllerContext, object> mycondition)
    {
        filterconditions.Add(mycondition);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return from filtercondition in filterconditions
               select filtercondition(controllerContext) into ctrlContext
               where ctrlContext!= null
               select new Filter(ctrlContext, FilterScope.Global);
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        MyFilterProvider provider = new MyFilterProvider();
        provider.Add(d => d.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() != "SkipFilterAction1 " ? new CompressContentAttribute() : null);
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);

        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new MinifyHtmlAttribute());
        filters.Add(new MinifyXmlAttribute());
    }
```